# What were the ranks in the Army of Imperial Spain?

Tags: military, 19th-century, spain, government, spanish-empire

At the time of the Latin American wars of independence, the Imperial Spanish army employed men in ranks like *Capitán* (captain), *Sargento* (sergeant) and so on, between the King and the lowliest footsoldier. [Wikipedia suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Army#18th_century) that "Royal Ordinances for the Regime, Discipline, Subordination and Service in his Armies" of 1768 was in place, but the Naopleonic Wars may have occasioned some reforms.

What were the military ranks used by the Spanish Empire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Spanish Commissioned Ranks

The [biography of Joaquín Blake y Joyes on the Napoleonic Series](https://www.napoleon-series.org/research/biographies/c_blake.html) traces his promotion history as:

- 1774 enrolls as an officer cadet (at 14 years age!)
- 1775: commissioned as **Subteniente de fusileros**;
- 1777: *appointed* as **maestro de cadetes**
- 1781: promoted to **Subteniente de granaderos** (likely a *lateral* recognition from a *command perspective* much as a modern medal for gallantry, though I cannot prove that just now);
- 1782: promoted to **Teniente** (likely *provisional*, as not yet employed in that rank);
- 1784: promoted to ***vivo* Teniente** (ie with an actual posting, and thus pay, at that rank);
- 1787: promoted to **Teniente de granaderos** (again likely a lateral move from a strict *command perspective*);
- 1791: promoted to **Capitán**;
- 1793: promoted to **Sargento Mayor** (sic - This is a fully commissioned rank; see my history notes below.)
- 1795: promoted to **Teniente Coronel** and then to **Coronel** (likely *provisional*, as see following); then he first requests retirement (sources differ on whether this was accepted or not), and subsequently requests to be made ***vivo* Coronel** rank (ie with both pay and appointment).
- 1802: promoted to **General de brigada**;
- 1810: promoted to **Teniente General** ([skipping **Mariscal de campo**!](https://www.napoleon-series.org/research/biographies/c_blake1.html));
- 1811: promoted to **Capitán General** (a *four-star* rank until a reorganization of the Spanish ranks in 1999; see below).

#### Notes:

1. Before the modern profusion of ribbons (a 19th century phenomena) it was common to distinguish both officers and other ranks at the battalion level by a *lateral* promotion into the grenadier company. We see *Blake y Joyes* being recognized twice with this distinction. It may or may not have included a pay raise.
2. The rank of **Sargento Mayor** is at this time the proper title of a fully commissioned rank superior to that of **Capitán** and inferior to that of **Teniente Coronel**. Ie it is exactly equivalent to our modern (English) rank of **Major** and the the modern Spanish rank of [**Commandante**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commandant_(rank)#Spain).
3. The rank of **Mariscal de campo** is already longstanding in Spanish usage by 1790, directly junior to a **Teniente general**, unlike the precedence of its literal translation into English as *Field Marshal*. Likewise in historical Austrian usage the ranks *Feldmarschall* and *Feldmarschallleutnant* cannot be assumed to have the same seniority as more modern English and Prussian (German) usage.
4. From the time of Philip V until a reorganization of 1889, the Spanish style for the two-star rank was [**Mariscal de campo**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariscal_de_campo) as noted by the promotion history of *Blake y Joyes*' contemporary [Francisco Javier Castaños](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Javier_Casta%C3%B1os):

   > At 10 years of age, Castaños received the rank of **capitán de infantería**, which King Carlos III granted him in attention to the merits of his father. He went on to study, as a young officer, [at] the *Seminario de Nobles*, training that would later be completed at the *Academia de Barcelona*.

   - 1782: promoted to **Sargento Mayor**;
   - 1784: promoted to **Teniente Coronel**;
   - 1789: promoted to **Coronal**;
   - 1794: promoted to **General de brigada**;
   - 1795: promoted to **Mariscal de campo**;
   - 1802: promoted to **Teniente General**;
   - 1808: promoted to **Capitán General**.

---

### Spanish Enlisted Ranks

In regards to other ranks, [Osprey's *Spanish Army of the Napoleonic Wars (1) 1793-1808*](https://the-eye.eu/public/WorldTracker.org/World%20History/Napoleonic%20%26%20Revolutionary%20Wars%20-%201792-1815/Osprey%20-%20Men%20at%20Arms%20321%20-%20Spanish%20army%20of%20the%20Napoleonic%20Wars%20part%201%20-%201793-1808.pdf) (pp 19-20) list the official establishment of Spanish line infantry regiments (in the early 1790's) as:

[image]
[image]

Based on the [cognate names of the modern Spanish ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_of_Spain) I suggest that these other ranks were names as, in increasing seniority:

- **Soldado**
- **Carabinier** (cavalry only); possibly also **Soldado primero** (infantry only) though as yet unattested in my research for the late 18th and early 19th century.
- **Cabo**
- **Cabo primero**
- **Sargento**
- **Sargento primero**
- **Alférez** (En: *ensign*: commissioned cavalry equivalent of **Subteniente**)

[Osprey's *Spanish Armies of the Napoleonic Wars*](https://the-eye.eu/public/WorldTracker.org/World%20History/Napoleonic%20%26%20Revolutionary%20Wars%20-%201792-1815/Osprey%20-%20Men%20at%20Arms%20051%20-%20Spanish%20Army%20Of%20Napoleonic%20Wars.pdf) notes (pp 17) that the officer ranks were allocated one third each to:

- promotion from the ranks (but generally restricted from rising higher than **Capitán**;
- purchase by the middle class; and
- purchase by the nobility

although (1) proof of noble descent was supposed to have been provided by all cavalry officers; and (2) virtually all ranks of **Coronel** and above were held only by those with noble descent (though matrilineal descent several generations back from the [Duke of Parma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Farnese,_Duke_of_Parma) or [Duke of Alba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_%C3%81lvarez_de_Toledo,_3rd_Duke_of_Alba) was probably sufficient).

Exactly what rank (and where in line of command) the additional appointments sat remains unclear to me for now:

- trumpeter (cavalry), kettle drummer (cavalry), or drummer (infantry)
- drum major (infantry) or trumpet major (cavalry)
- master armouorer
- master saddler (cavalry)
- chaplain
- surgeon

[Earlier research of mid-19th century British practices](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/47459/can-the-assignment-depot-battalion-in-harts-annual-army-list-be-linked-to-a-s/47462#47462) suggests that these are appointments with a minimum rank requirement (I'm guessing **Cabo primero** for most, **Sargento** for those styled *major*, *master*, or requiring higher education) and a small pay supplement.

---

### History

#### IE: Why the nomenclature *Major* recur across enlisted, warranted, and commissioned ranks with varying implied seniority

Without a more specific time period, let's review quickly the history and development of the modern infantry arms' command and organizational structure in Western Europe from say 1568 (start of Eighty Years War) until 1815. I believe this will illustrate the basic pattern that then can be adjusted for national variations between Spain, Britain, France and Prussia.

As we leave the late Medieval period the basic components of an army are a mixture of medieval levies and *mercenary companies. In both of these it had became common to denote the senior enlisted man in each *company* of about 100 or so men as the (company) Sergeant-Major. Reporting directly to the Captain of the company, he functioned as a chief-of-staff and was the third *officer of the company, after the Captain and his Lieutenant. Larger organization of the army through most of the 15th century remains an *ad hoc* structure of *wings* and *attack waves*, with armies small enough to comfortably travel on a single road.

With the development of *pike-and-ball* warfare, and larger (professional!) armies, mobility on both attack and defence returns to the battlefield. To facilitate this a more permanent grouping of companies (now usually standardized at 100-120 men) into *battle-groups* (*battalions*) develops, with these *battalions* in turn *brigaded* (usually three at a time) to provide a two level hierarchy of command and control. Mimicking the historical organization of our *companies*, these battalions and brigades in turn appoint a *Battalion Sergeant-Major* (still an enlisted man) and a *Brigade Sergeant-Major* (now a commissioned officer).

The distinction between *rank* and *title* or *office* is just developing, and the command structure remains quite simple, with each brigade command structure something like this (assuming for discussion three battalions of four companies each):

- 1 * Colonel (Sp.: *Coronel*)
- 1 * Lieutenant Colonel (Sp.: *Teniente coronel*)
- 13 * Captain (Sp.: *Capitán*) - the most senior holding the **title** of *Brigade Sergeant-Major* (Sp., eventually: *Commandante*), acting as *chief-of-staff* to the Colonel, and **commanding** the third battalion.
- 12 * Lieutenant (Sp.: *Teniente*)
- n * Sergeant (Sp.: *Sargento*)

  - 3 (one per battalion) holding the **title** of *Battalion Sergeant-Major* (Sp.: *Subofficiel mayor*) and acting as *chief-of-staff* for each battalion with responsibility for logistics of the battalion: ammunition in battle and food on the march.
  - 12 (1 per company) holding the **title** of *Company Sergeant-Major* (Sp.: *Subteniente*), acting as *chief-of-staff* for each captain with responsibility for discipline and training of the men

Notes:

1. The strict assignment of ranks and titles to hierarchical responsibility strictly limits availability of the ranks and titles.
2. At this time the epithet *sergeant* still retains its late Medieval euphemism of seniority and command - but that will soon wane as the term becomes restricted to non-commissioned rank.
3. The new **title** of *Brigade Sergeant-Major* is the first with command, in addition to support, responsibility. This also likely relates to the looming drop of the *Sergeant* from the position name.
4. At various times the structure above may or may not have a *regiment* (or *demi-brigade) structure between the *brigade* and the *battalion*. This varies by era and nationality, but does not affect the general concept above. It's presence makes brigades about twice as strong.

However our armies of the time are already much larger than a brigade or even a small number of brigades. In some countries (notably United Kingdom and Austro-Hungary) the right to be paid to raise a regiment was sold by the crown, with regimental commissions resold in turn by the Colonels/[Inhabers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhaber). At a national level the need arose for *general officers*, those holding commissions directly from the crown and with responsibility and authority over multiple regiments and brigades. (It is best at this time to think of the word *general* as an adjective rather than, as currently, a noun.)

- In English usage there was a single *General Officer* for each independent command of an army, with a [*Lieutenant General (Officer)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lieutenant_general) as his second in command and the [*Sergeant-Major General*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergeant_major_general) as his *chief-of-staff*.
- The French regarded, through this time period, all commands above that of a division (*General de Division* being the equivalent of English *Major General*) as appointments; so that rank was the highest available.

  Strictly speaking the style *Marshal of the Empire* was always merely a title; but as all the holders uniformly refused to accept orders or direction from any officer not holding it, it became a *de facto* rank if not a *de jure* one.
- The Spanish modelled it as an upgraded company commanded by a [*Captain General*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_general) assisted by a *Lieutenant General* and a *Mariscal de campo* (the latter being renamed in 1889, after the French model, as  *General de división*).
- The [Prussians under Frederick](http://mapswar2.x10host.com/Prussian_army_of_Frederick_the_Great.htm#_Military_Ranks_Command_Structure) likewise modelled the independent army as (a collection of) companies (ie wings or columns), each commanded by a *General der Infanterie*, *der Cavalerie*, or *der Artillerie* and assisted by a *Lieutenant General*. (The branch names in the title had no battlefield command significance, but merely signified rank and perhaps the origin of the possessor.) As noted in that link Frederick had no use for the rank of *Feldmarschall* since that authority was always personally vested in himself.
- The Austrians innovate with the *Field Marshal* assisted by an *Lieutenant Field Marshal*.

As armies became too large to travel on a single road and are divided into *columns* (the less flexible precursor of Napoleon's *Corps d'Armee*), each in turn is the responsibility of a Lieutenant General (or equivalent), with the Austrian cavalry column commanded by a General of Cavalry. However they all (initially) retain the **title** of *Sergeant-Major General* as that of the *chief-of-staff* of the (independent) army. This brings us to the early Napoleonic period, when the *Sergeant-* prefix is dropped from the commissioned titles to yield:

- *Brigade Sergeant-Major* becomes first *Brigade Major* and then just *Major*; and
- *Sergeant-Major General* becomes *Major General*.

---

I have made some generalizations here based on the English etymology of the ranks and titles. More complex national (and branch: artillery vs cavalry vs artillery) variations exist. The French (singularly I believe) retain *Major General* as a title rather than a rank, dating back to the appointment of Berthier as "The Major General of the Grand Army" by Napoleon - with the rank being *Generale de Division*.

Of import for specific Spanish usage: the rank of Captain General was upgraded in 1999 from a 4-star equivalent to a 5-star equivalent for conformity with NATO usage, with a new 4-star rank of [*General of the Army (General de Ejército)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_of_the_Army_(Spain)) interceded in its place. [Spanish terminology varies slightly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_of_Spain), with specifically the rank of *Major* being termed *Commandante*.

---

The above summarizes four nationalities, several times as many sovereign states, and nearly three hundred years from the mid-16th to early 19th centuries, for west of the Elbe and south of the Baltic. There will be exceptions: by nationality, by branch, by time period, by personal style of the commanding officer, and even by regiment. To cover every exception would be the work of decades, and the size of an encyclopedia.

Hopefully the discussion above provides sufficient context and structure for understanding the contemporary usage of that time period and place - so that for example when reading Saski and seeing the constant address "To The Major General ..." one understands why there was only one officer, Berthier, to be addressed as such.

Comment: Holy Shit! This is incredibly fascinating. Any idea how the ten year old thing happened I am seriously curious at this point.

Comment: @TanzaniteDragoness: As with Royal Navy midshipman appointments of a similar age - for early seniority. Most promotions up to **Teniente Coronal** were seniority based, within one's regiment ; absent combat losses this could take a decade or two. The father being accomplished and the boy having shown interest, the lad was commissioned in hope that he would then be eligible for promotion to **Sargento Mayor** by his mid- to late-twenties and past the bottleneck at **Capitain**.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I could find was a [New York Times Article dates 1862](http://www.nytimes.com/1862/01/13/news/naval-military-forces-spain-their-history-their-actual-organization-strength.html?pagewanted=all) which described the military forces of Spain, with reference to ranks. These ranks were probably replicated throughout the Spanish Empire.

> The general officers of the Spanish Army at the present time consist
>   of
>
> Captain-Generals.................................. 10
>
> Lieutenant-Generals............................... 61
>
> Marshals of Camp..................................142
>
> Brigadiers........................................375
>
> Total.............................................588
>
> The Staff of the Army comprises: 3 brigadiers, 9 colonels, 12
>   lieutenant-colonels, 25 commandants, 60 captains, and 40 lieutenants.
>
> The Royal Corps of Halberdiers consists of 43 officers, and 240 rank
>   and file. Total, 283 men.
>
> The Infantry comprises 5,972 officers, and 164,000 rank and file,
>   making a total of 109,972 men. They are organized as follows:
>
> Forty regiments of the line of two battalions.
>
> One regiment of three battalions. permanently stationed at Ceuta.
>
> Twenty battalions of Chasseurs.
>
> Eighty battalions of reserve, (provinciales.)
>
> During the war in Africa, these eighty battalions of reserve furnished
>   60,000 men, with 1,613 officers.
>
> The Cavalry comprises 968 officers, and 14,600 rank and file. Total,
>   15,568 men, with 14,710 horses. There are also 376 men belonging to
>   the General School of Cavalry. The organization is as follows:
>
> Four regiments of Carabineers.
>
> Four regiments of Cuirassiers.
>
> Six regiments of Lancers.
>
> Four regiments of Chasseurs.
>
> Two regiments of Hussars.
>
> Two squadrons of Chasseurs.
>
> Four squadrons of Remounts.
>
> The twenty regiments are each divided into three squadrons, with 520
>   men in each squadron.
>
> The Artillery comprises 689 officers and 11,680 rank and file. Total
>   number of men 12,369, with 2,600 horses. They are divided as under:
>
> Five regiments of foot Artillery.
>
> Four brigades of mounted Artillery.
>
> Two brigades of mountain Artillery.
>
> One brigade of horse Artillery.
>
> Five brigades of foot Artillery, (fixed in garrisons.)
>
> The Engineers comprise 256 officers and 3,760 rank and file. Total,
>   4,016 men. They are divided into two regiments, of two battalions
>   each.
>
> The Gendarmerie, or civil guard, comprise 451 officers and 12,500 men.
>   Total, 12,951, with 1,500 horses.
>
> The Militia of the Canaries is divided into six battalions of
>   Provinciales, three sections of ditto, and seventeen companies of
>   artillery. The entire force of this militia is 225 officers and 7,104
>   rank and file. Total, 7,329 men.
>
> The Corps of Carabineers comprises 499 officers and 11,285 rank and
>   file. Total 11,784 men, with 1,200 horses.
>
> The Corps of Catalonia contains 16 officers and 500 rank and file.
>   Total, 516 men.
>
> The total military force of Spain is as under:
>
> Men. Horses.
>
> Royal Corps of Halberdiers........ 285 --
>
> The Infantry...................169,972 --
>
> The Cavalry.................... 15,568 14,710
>
> The Artillery.................. 12,369 2,600
>
> The Engineers.................. 4,016 --
>
> The Gendarmerie................ 12,951 1,500
>
> Militia of the Canaries........ 7,329 --
>
> Corps of Carabineers........... 11,784 1,200
>
> Corps of Catalonia............. 516 --
>
> Total.......................... 234,788 20,010
>
> Of the total number of soldiers 9,119 are officers and 225,669 rank and file.

Comment: This is close to being the answer but only addresses officers. I hope to see the Spanish terms and in strict order.