# Did any British police force rank "Senior Superintendent"?

Tags: police

[Hong Kong Police Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Police_Force#Ranks_and_insignia) ranks "Senior Superintendent".

> [Senior Superintendent of Police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintendent_(police)) (SSP) (Traditional Chinese: [高](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%AB%98)[級](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B4%9A)[警](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%AD%A6)[司](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%B8)): crest over pip.

[Picture](https://www.police.gov.hk/ppp_en/01_about_us/os_chart.html).

[image]

But I don't see "Senior Superintendent" on [Wikipedia "Great Britain Police Ranks and Insignia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_ranks_of_the_United_Kingdom#Defunct_rank_insignia)  or its headings for City of London or Metropolitan Police. Superintendent jumps to Chief Superintendent.

[image]

If answer is no, what happened to rank SSP in U.K.? Why no more SSP?

Comment: What leads you to believe the rank ever existed in the British Police? Different jurisdictions and nationalities frequently have "*equivalent ranks*" with different names. For instance the Spanish military rank of *Commandante* is an OF3 between a *Capitánand* a *Teniente coronel*just as the English rank of *Major* is an OF-3 between a *Captain* and a *Lieutenant Colonel* - yet the names are different. Don't even get me started on the four different *levels of seniority* at which German speaking *Feldmarshals* have existed over the last 250 years.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Before July 1 1997, Hong Kong police WAS British Police, or Royal Hong Kong Police.  Even now Hong Kong police has British expats serving as senior officers.

Comment: Google Books shows 19th century instances of "Senior Superintendent of Police" being used in places like the Punjab, New South Wales, etc.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Please tell about the four different levels of seniority! (I can open a new question if you like). I am only aware of two.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: I separate question would be worthwhile - comments being ephemeral and all that. However (European, not all German) from circa 1809: 1) Spanish [Mariscal de campo](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/what-were-the-ranks-in-the-army-of-imperial-spain) is a 2 star rank as is Austrian Feldmarschall-Leutnant; (2) French Marshal of the Empire is a 3-star equivalent (an appointment, *de jure*, but a rank *de facto*) (3) Austrian (and Russian) Feldmarschall is a 4 star rank above General der Kavalerie and Feldzeugmeister but below Generalissimo; (4) Modern Field Marshals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your answer appears to be on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Police_Force#Ranks_and_insignia)

The rank structure, organisation and insignia are similar to those used by the Metropolitan Police Service until the mid-1970s.[41]

[41] on wiki is:

http://uniforminsignia.org/?option=com_insigniasearch&Itemid=53&result=2711

which shows 3 superintendent ranks from 1954 - 1973: Grade II, Grade I, and Chief. It is plausible that 'Grade I' can be called 'Senior'.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official web site of the [Hong Kong Police Service](https://www.police.gov.hk/ppp_en/index.html), on both it's [Rank and Promotion page](https://www.police.gov.hk/ppp_en/11_useful_info/aux_police/rp.html)

> [image]

and [Organization Chart](https://www.police.gov.hk/ppp_en/11_useful_info/aux_police/oc.html) page

> [image]

both Chief Superintendent (CSP) and Senior Superintendent (SSP) are extant ranks in the service.

According to your [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Police_Force#Ranks_and_insignia) reference, the traditional Chinese and insignia are:

- Chief Superintendent: (Traditional Chinese: 總警司): crest over two pips.
- Senior Superintendent: (SSP) (Traditional Chinese: 高級警司): crest over pip.

Comparing to British Police Services, there is considerable variation in the *gazetted ranks* between for example Scotland Yard, London Police, and Metropolitan Police. This is to be expected, with the size and responsibility
of the various services varying considerably - the larger forces having an additional rank or two at the top level.

- [Scotland Yard:](https://www.hierarchystructure.com/scotland-yard-police-hierarchy/)

> [image]

- [Metropolitan Police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_ranks_of_the_United_Kingdom):

> [image]

- [City of London Police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_ranks_of_the_United_Kingdom):

> [image]

Note that while City of London has just 5 ranks above Chief Inspector, the Metropolitan Police and Scotland Yard have 7. Hong Kong also has just 5, the same as City of London, befitting a force of similar size and responsibility. Northern Ireland also has 5, while the Isle of Man has only three. It's less about the precise names for the *gazetted ranks*, though the common history clearly shows, but rather the responsibilities.